Bloom filter - Privacy & Sensitive data
Is it ok to store sensitive data (such as usernames) in a Bloom filter?
Is there a risk of reverse-engineering the filter's contents?
If so, what measures can I take to enhance the security of my data?
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any articles for those questions.
Edit:
There are a couple of key points to highlight:

I have no intention of exposing my Bloom filter. My top concern lies in the possibility that an attacker could somehow gain access to it and understand the inserted data.
Let's hypothetically say my Bloom filter contains the full names of all Ashley Madison users. Is there any method to prevent attackers from guessing what names have been inserted? (encryption or Bloom filter hardening)?


My top concern with exposing a Bloom filter is that some random joker can attack your site by filling junk into your Bloom filter. And now it no longer does its job, and your site's ability to handle load is compromised.
But let's talk about the risk that you identify. Because Bloom filters are lossy, nobody can reverse engineer what is actually in one. But if someone has a reasonable guess about what they think might be there, they can verify that their guess is probably right.
For example let's take Patrick McKenzie. He's patio11 all over the internet. And I've never seen anyone else pretend to be him. So if I find a user on your site named patio11, it is a reasonable guess that he was there. (I reuse btilly in places, but lots of other people also use that. That's why I picked on him.)
For most sites, he probably wouldn't care if that fact was exposed. But for some sites, he would. Whether he would care about your site is going to depend on what your site does. If you're sharing cat pictures, it's fine. If you're a bank or porn site, it's probably not fine.
But putting it into a Bloom filter that is locked away is OK, even if you do not wish to expose it.

First, thank you for your response. There are a couple of key points to highlight:

I have no intention of exposing my Bloom filter. My top concern lies in the possibility that an attacker could somehow gain access to it and understand the inserted data.
About my website, let's hypothetically say my Bloom filter contains the full names of all Ashley Madison users. Based on your answer, I understand an attacker could determine if a specific name is present, but not the entire names, am i correct?

Is there any method to prevent this, such as encryption or Bloom filter hardening?

@Samuel Yes, you're understanding is correct. The most obvious thing to do is make a minor change in the hashing. Now they need your source code to figure out how to access the Bloom filter. But if they have your system compromised, that's only a speed bump. Depending on how you're using it, you could store user_name + client_secret in the filter. Even with complete access, they need the client_secret to search the filter. And they can't get it from you because you never stored it. That seems like it should work, but run it by a security expert before trusting my advice.

There are two approaches you could consider to mitigate potential attacks:

Read-only access:
You can provide read-only access to the Bloom filter. This prevents an attacker from modifying the filter's contents while still allowing legitimate use.

High false-positive rate:
Implement a Bloom filter with a high false-positive error rate, such as 10%. This approach:

Maintains usefulness for certain use cases
Reduces the reliability of any data an intruder might attempt to extract as the chance of a mistake is quite high



